# C++ Disable Busy/Waiting Cursor

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cursor

Im creating a small program that runs in background and does some custom tasks for me like copying certain files, removing, showing and hiding files. Anyways its not important.

The problem is that when some tasks are performed my cursor changes to that busy/waiting cursor (rotating circle thingy in win7). Its not critical problem but I was wondering if I can disable it in C++.

TL:DR - I want to disable/remove the busy cursor (using C++) at least for duration of my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The busy cursor occurs to me most of the time when Sleep() is being run on main thread. If that's the case in your situation as well, try postponing actions with [timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644901(v=vs.85).aspx) instead, if not, the option I can think of is to add all these tasks on another thread using [CreateThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx).